# unable to load XML data using Copy data activity

Tags: sql-server, xml, azure-data-factory

I am unable to load the XML data using copy data activity in sql server DB, but am able to achieve this with data flows using flatten hierarchy , while mapping the corresponding array is not coming properly in copy data even pipeline success also only partial  data is loading in DB.

and auto creation of table is also not allowing while doing copy activity for XML file , has to create table script first and load the data ...

as we are using SHIR this activity should be done in using copy data activity.

Comment: What is your question here exactly? You don't appear to ask anything.

Answer (score 0):

- Use the collection reference in mapping tab of copy activity to unroll by and extract the data. I repro'd this using copy activity with sample nested XML data.

[image]
img1: source dataset preview.

- In mapping tab, Select **Import schemas**
- Toggle on the **Advanced editor**
- Give the json path of the array from which data needs to be iterated and extracted.

[image]
img:2 Mapping settings.

- When pipeline is run, data is copied successfully to database.
  [image]
  img:3 sink data after copying.

Reference : **MS document** on [hierarchical source to tabular sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#hierarchical-source-to-tabular-sink).

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation , but in the XML file have one is meta data another is transactional data ...by using collection reference i can select only one array

Comment: In this case, you need to use dataflow only. You can copy data in some staging like Azure blob storage and then use dataflow